# Set a form to unsubmitted in AngularJS without using a reset button click

Tags: angularjs, forms, modal-dialog

I have a simple form housed in a modal dialog:

```
<div id="myModal6" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Please add Payment Details</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body clearfix">
            <form id="checkout" class="col-lg-12" ng-submit="checkoutForm.$valid && finishCheckout()" method="post" name="checkoutForm" novalidate>

                <input class="form-control card_number" required ng-model="customer.number" name="number1" ng-minlength=12  maxlength="22" placeholder="xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx">


                <div class="error" ng-show="(checkoutForm.$submitted || checkoutForm.number1.$dirty && checkoutForm.number1.$invalid) && payee">
                    <small class="error text-danger" ng-show="checkoutForm.number1.$error.required">
                        Card No is required.
                    </small>
                    <small class="error text-danger" ng-show="checkoutForm.number1.$error.minlength">
                        Card No is required to be at least 12 characters
                    </small>
                </div>

                <div class="card_form">
                    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="save">
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When a user clicks the submit button before adding anything to the text box, a validation message appears thanks to Angular. All is right in the world.

However, if a user then clicks the close button and returns to this modal later, the validation messages remains. I have found that using a reset button, I can pass the form object into a click handler to leverage the built-in $setPristine function to clear the validation of the form, but I would like to do this without having a reset button.

Is there a way I can access the $setPristine function of AngularJS without using a button to feed the form object into my angular scope?

EDIT:

I've added both of the following to my form:

```
    <div ng-init="initCardForm(checkoutForm)"></div>
    <input type="button" value="Reset Form" ng-click="resetCardForm(checkoutForm)" />
```

Along with their functions:

```
    $scope.initCardForm = function(form) { 
        $scope.myForm = form; 
        $scope.myForm.$setPristine(); 
    } 
    $scope.resetCardForm = function(form) { 
        $scope.myForm = form; 
        $scope.myForm.$setPristine(); 
    }
```

The reset button works, but the init call doesn't accomplish what I'm trying to do. I believe this may be related to modal loading on init it doesn't initialize every time the modal is called. My goal is that every time I show the modal popup, it sets the form to Pristine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer: Yes, you can.** You can do a little trick with `ng-init` and pass the form instance to controller. ([PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/nOhyx0ZZXjfGGYP8mCUS?p=preview))

***HTML***

```
<form name="myForm" class="col-lg-12" novalidate>
  <div ng-init="initForm(myForm)"></div>
  <!-- rest of your html -->
</form>
```

***CONTROLLER***

```
function MyCtrl () {
  $scope.myForm = {};

  $scope.initForm = function(form) {
    // Here you are assigning the form instance to your $scope variable
    $scope.myForm = form;

    //$scope.myForm.$pristine = true;
    //$scope.myForm.$dirty = true; 
    //etc...
  }
}
```

Comment: I've added both of the following to my form:

<div ng-init="initCardForm(checkoutForm)"></div>
<input type="button" value="Reset Form" ng-click="resetCardForm(checkoutForm)" />

Along with their functions:
    $scope.initCardForm = function(form) {
        $scope.myForm = form;
        $scope.myForm.$setPristine();
      }

    $scope.resetCardForm = function(form) {
        $scope.myForm = form;
        $scope.myForm.$setPristine();
    }

reset button works, but init doesn't. Believe this may be related to modal loading on init it doesn't initialize every time modal is called

Comment: I've tried, and every time that modal is opened the `ng-init` is called. Are you using plain bootstrap.js modal? Maybe you should use [angularjs ui boostrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#modal). It would make your life easier.

Comment: Yeah, we're just using plain bootstrap. Unfortunately for this issue, it's small enough that it's not worth swapping out the bootstrap framework, but you definitely answered the question. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [The.Bear](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3354228/the-bear)'s help, I was able to come up with a way to accomplish this in the full way I needed it. In my instance, the init on the div is being called only once at the load of the full page, not every time the modal is called. However, leveraging the example [The.Bear](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3354228/the-bear) gave I was able to set the form to pristine every time the modal was closed:

***HTML***

```
<div id="myModal6" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
...
  <form name="myForm" class="col-lg-12" novalidate>
    <div ng-init="initForm(myForm)"></div>
    <!-- rest of the form -->
  </form>
...
</div>
```

***CONTROLLER***

```
$scope.initCardForm = function(form) {
    console.log("garfield");
    $scope.myCardForm = form;
    $scope.myCardForm.$setPristine();

    $('#myModal6').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        $scope.resetCardForm();
    })
}

$scope.resetCardForm = function() {
    console.log("heathcliff");
    $scope.myCardForm.$setPristine();
}
```